# How do health boosts work?

Tags: naruto-blazing

I have a ton of health boosts that are taking up too much inventory space.

Can I use a health boost on a 1 star character to clear my inventory space and then enhance a higher star character later when I'm ready in order to transfer the stats?

Does it matter that I don't match up the attribute of the health boost to the character attribute in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use lower star characters and the bonus stats transfer. Be mindful that lower star chars cap out bonuses lower. And no, it doesn't matter what attribute.